# Using "SELECT" to display grouped result

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Name    | Type
Maurice | Gold
Lisa    | Gold
Andrew  | Silver
Matthew | Platinum
Sarah   | Gold
Peter   | Platinum
Franco  | Platinum
Patrick | Silver
```

I've been trying using 'select' to display them grouped by type, but I haven't found any right way. The result I'm looking are like this:

```
Silver   |  Gold    |  Platinum
Andrew   |  Maurice |  Matthew
Patrick  |  Lisa    |  Peter
NULL     |  Sarah   |  Franco
```

Is there anyway to make the result look like that? Thank you!

Comment: select * from 'table_name' group by type;

Comment: to fetch the group name you can try like this [select group_field from table_name group by group_field]. Note "type" is a keyword, chang your field name from "type" to some other name.

Comment: You're looking for an operation called *pivoting* the table. It's a notorious pain in the neck in MySQL.

Comment: Generally, issues of data display are best resolved in application level code, if that's available (e.g. a simple PHP loop)

Comment: Better do this in application level. Just use a simple query to get the records  `SELECT Name,Type FROM your_table order by type`

Answer (score 0):

```
select  (case when type='Silver' then  name  end) as silver,
        (case when type='Gold' then  name  end) as gold,
        (case when type='Platinum' then  name  end) as platinum
from table_name
```

Comment: thanks, this looks good but there's so many null appear

is there any way to remove the null?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!